# Does this SMART result indicate brand new drive?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, smart, smartctl

Bought a Seagate Exos 7e drive from an OEM reseller (no Seagate warranty). **Are these SMART results valid for a drive that is supposed to be brand new**?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Look for the POH. Power_On_Hours (POH) is the length of time, usually in hours, that electrical power has been applied to a device. In your case "0".

Which does **not** mean this SMART attribute could not have been manipulated.

Comment: Smart manipulation, as in a total re-write is possible? I will google that.